# echoid.exe remote execution issue (wrong Locking Code output)

Tags: locking, echo, remote-execution

I am trying to bring **locking code** of a farm in automatic way.
 So, i have on each remote server echoid.exe and a batch file.
The batch file simply execute the **echoid.exe** and write its output into a text file which i can parse. 
The problem is when im triggering the .bat  file remotely, it seems like the echoid.exe executed on the **container host** (the one im using to send execution command through psexec for example) rather than executing the code in the remote host (meaning- the locking code output is wrong) . If the same .bat file executed locally (and manually), the results are OK.
Any idea why? does anyone know how can i run the echoid remotely and get the **correct** results? 
i have tried several remote action and all failed and brought wrong results :(
please help!
BTW all remote machines are WIN OS.

Comment: Could you show the code / bat?

Comment: c:\echoid.exe > c:\LockingCode.txt

Comment: andddd....im running the following command from remote server: psexec \\REMOTE-SERVER\ -u administrator -p somePW c:\echoid